# php sort multidimensional array key ascending

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have this array:

```
Array => (
    [0] => Array(
        [a] => hello,
        [b] => world
    ),
    [1] => Array(
        [a] => bye,
        [b] => planet
    ),
    .....
)
```

And I need a function to sort it into this:

```
Array => (
    [0] => Array(
        [a] => bye,
        [b] => planet
    ),
    [1] => Array(
        [a] => hello,
        [b] => world
    ),
    .....
)
```

Been hours trying and I am going mad, please help me.

Thanks!!

Comment: What is the basis for the sort behavior you want?  Why should the elements shown swap places when sorted? That is not clear in your question. Is it alphabetical order by whatever value is at index `a`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean to sort the array based on the contents of all the strings in the array, you're going to have to apply some logic to the sort. Using [`usort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) allows us to pass in an arbitrary function to perform the comparison.

```
usort($my_array, function ($a, $b) {
    return strcasecmp(implode($a), implode($b));
});
```

This way, it'll compare two arrays like so:

```
array 1 = [ 'foo', 'bar' ]
array 2 = [ 'baz', 'quux' ]
array 1 is converted to "foobar"
array 2 converted to "bazquux"
compare strings "foobar" to "bazquux"
-> "bazquux" comes first alphabetically, so strcasecmp() return positive integer
-> usort receives the positive integer which informs its sorting algorithm
```

Comment: And before anyone says so, yes I know this doesn't care about child array ordering, and I know this will break if the array is multi-tiered.

Answer (score 0):

You could use array_reverse(). PHP has many built in array functions.
http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php

```
$test = Array (
    0 => Array(
        'a' => 'hello',
        'b' => 'world'
),
    1 => Array(
        'a' => 'bye',
        'b' => 'planet'
    ),
);
$reverse = array_reverse($test);
print_r($reverse);
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [a] => bye 
        [b] => planet 
    ) 
    [1] => Array ( 
       [a] => hello 
       [b] => world 
    )
 )
```

Comment: The OP said sort, not reverse. What about the implied arbitrary elements in the OP `...`?